# Showing that a Group Extension is Split

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, semidirect-product, group-extensions, wreath-product

I have a group extension $1\rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 1$ that I think is a split extension (so $G \approx N \rtimes Q$), but I'm having trouble showing this.  Is there a general strategy for how to define the section $Q \rightarrow G$?  If possible, I would like to have an explicit mapping $Q \rightarrow G$ or $N \rtimes Q \overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} G$.

For some additional details on the specific case, $G \leq H \wr_{\Omega} Q = \mathrm{Fun(\Omega, H)} \rtimes Q$ and $N = \ker (G \twoheadrightarrow Q)$ (where this mapping is surjective).

**EDIT:**
I've computed some examples of $G$ (which show up as monodromy groups of certain coverings) and in each case, it seemed to be a semidirect product: $C_{m} \rtimes C_{2}$ (for any $m$), $A_{7} \wr C_{2}$, $(S_{5} \times S_{5}) \rtimes C_{2}$, $C_{7} \rtimes A_{5}$, $(C_{2}^{18} \rtimes C_{3}^{8}) \rtimes S_{9}$, $C_{7}^{6} \rtimes A_{5}$, etc.

However, when I was going back through all of my examples, I found $C_{2}^{6} \rtimes C_{9}$, but as an extension $1 \rightarrow C_{2}^{6} \rtimes C_{3} \rightarrow C_{2}^{6} \rtimes C_{9} \rightarrow C_{3} \rightarrow 1$.  Based on what I've read about $C_{4}$ not being a split extension of $C_{3}$, I assume that $C_{2}^{6} \rtimes C_{9} \not\approx (C_{2}^{6} \rtimes C_{3}) \rtimes C_{3}$ and $G$ is, in fact, not always a split extension.

This might be why I was having trouble defining the section $Q \rightarrow G$ in the general case.

Comment: You’ll need to give more details: not every such $G$ is a split extension. For example, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ embeds into $\mathbb{Z}_2\wr\mathbb{Z}_2$, and the canonical projection onto $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is surjective when restricted to $G$. But $G$ is not split.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin When I was looking through my examples, I found the extension $1 \rightarrow C_{2}^{6} \rtimes C_{3} \rightarrow C_{2}^{6} \rtimes C_{9} \rightarrow C_{3} \rightarrow 1$, which I think is non-split.  So it looks like $G$ is not always a split extension afterall.

Comment: By a Theorem of Kaloujnine and Krasner, every extension of $H$ by $K$ can be embedded in the unrestricted regular wreath product $H\wr K$, and that embedding will have surjective projection onto $K$. So there will be a lot of examples where you cannot have a section, namely whenever the extension in question is not a split extension. That's why you need more information.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yeah, I was hoping for some kind of general approach, "if I have an explicit finite group, this is how I can determine if it's a semidirect product".  GAP has a function ```SemidirectDecompositions```, though I'm not sure it's one a human could follow.  But this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1587091/120503 indicates that this is a rather difficult problem in general.